# How to improve CLS Score in Mobile View above the fold content in Magento2 website?

Tags: magento2, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to improve my Magento website speed. In Mobile view, I am getting below issue in Google Pagespeed.
Avoid large layout shifts 5 elements found in mobile view. 4 elements from an iframe. And another one is normal text. I am wondering why it's showing for normal text. I have added font-display: swap. If I checked with the image also showing the CLS issue. This content is above the fold section in the mobile view.
How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: The text is just a preview of what the element that is shifting contains. The `div` marked in blue is the element that needs to be fixed. The best way to fix CLS problems is to reserve space in the browser for whatever element is in the list in your screenshot, e.g `div='trust-worthy-block'`

Answer (score 0):

1. For CLS fix : you should identify on whats the element responsible, make sure that there is a dummy image or an element of that size.

Bread crumbs on times are known as one of the elements of layout shift.
Images too can be the reason.

Share site URL to check further.